# How to get location of the element after it was clicked?

Tags: javascript

I have `HTML element(span)` the changes it's location.When I click `HTML element(span)` I need to get the `HTML element(span)'s` location.

Here is html:

```
<span class="btnFlyout" id="btn4" style="width: 52px; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);" 
                                                                        onmouseover="HoverButton('btn4', null)" 
                                                                        onmouseout="LeaveButton('btn4', '')" 
                                                                        onclick="OpenFlyout('cell4', 4, event)">
  <span class="txtFlyout" style="left: 4px;"> measure </span>
    <img class="arrowFlyout" src="../stdicons/icon_menuarrow.gif" style="left: 32px;" width="16px" height="16px" hspace="2" vspace="2">
  </span>
```

Here is onclick event:

```
  function OpenFlyout(xpos, tbItemIndex, e)
  {

  }
```

How can I get HTML element(span) location in OpenFlyout function?

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for post.can you clearefy?

Comment: yes ... use getBoundingClientRect to get the elements bounding client rectangle